# Facebook like button in site that uses post message spams console

Tags: javascript, facebook, postmessage

I have a site that uses a lot of postMessage communication between iframes.  Putting a Facebook like button in my site causes my debug console to get spammed with messages like

Received message of type object from [domain], expected a string.

This makes development very difficult.  Is there any way to prevent this extra logging from occurring?  I am new to using facebooks apis so I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple.  They can't possibly assume that no one besides them will ever use postmessage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that's not an extra logging. It's from the Facebook SDK. Simply you can uglify the sdk for removing all console from the library.

1.Download the sdk. https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js

2.Uglify it for removing console logging (production version.)
https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

3.Use it in your site.

Another link which may help you:
http://elijahmanor.com/grunt-away-those-pesky-console-log-statements/

Answer (score 4):

Actually, disabling console.log is a horrible answer. What if we want to use console.log, but just want to stop the spamming error message? What is causing it? How do we actually fix it?

Comment: This is not an answer, please use a comment instead

Comment: It's really the only answer for the question that was asked. I wouldn't advise completely disabling console.log as the answer stated, but not much else can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply "unset" the console.log function, by doing something like:

```
console.log = function(){}
```

Save it in another variable first, for example:

```
var originalLog = console.log;
```

Now when the Facebook API tries to use the log function nothing will happen. If you need to use the log function, just enable it first by setting it back to your saved originalLog variable and unset it when you are done using it. Unhandled errors will still show up in your console, regardless of what you have done to the log function.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this was caused by the FVD Video Downloader extension, so maybe you should disable all browser extensions and see if that solves the issue, then enable them back one by one to find the culprit.